# TFS - tools to edit email template of build notification

Tags: email-templates

Are there any tools available, which gives a wizard to edit the email format for the notifications sent after build done by TFS.
i tried to find out how to edit email format for project alerts. and got many articles where they provided path for "transforms" folder and said that there would be eMailTemplate. but i got only one file

> "TeamFoundation.xsl"

at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application
>   Tier\Web Services_tfs_resources\Services\v1.0\Transforms

please let me know if there are any tools available from where i can easily change the email template of TFS.

Comment: how complex is your change? xsl can be edited with a text editor fairly easily, or visual studio if you want intellisense + syntax highlighting.